# MongoDB restore from file backup

Tags: mongodb, backup, restore

I have a backup of /data/db that contains all .wt files along with journal directory etc. I have stopped the db, replaced the current db directory with the one backed up and started the db. This works, Mongo starts up but when I "show databases" there are no results. The local machine (that was backed up) did not have authentication enabled. The machine I am using to attempt the restore does have it enabled, I am able to start the mongo client without any authentication.

Is there another step to this process?
Is the authentication difference an issue?

Comment: Really nothing? Not even the internal DB's `local`,`config`,`admin`? Did you copy the files to correct `dbPath`?

Comment: If the `show dbs` is giving really nothing, you might have used authentication before and that's the reason when you login without auth you are not seeing any databases.